# Ignore cells where text is empty regardless of formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a snippet of code to run through multiple worksheets and, if the value in column "h" is not empty, copy each sheet row-by-row to a master summary sheet. My problem is that every cell in column "h" contains a CONCATENATE formula, but of course if the rest of the row is empty then the CONCATENATE returns an empty or 0 value. For some reason the following code is failing to ignore these rows. (Note: w is the object representing the current worksheet, and dest is the object representing the destination worksheet where rows will be copied to.)

```
Last = w.Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row
For a = 2 To Last Step 1
    If w.Cells(a, "h").Text <> "" Or w.Cells(a, "h").Text <> "0" Then
    d = dest.Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    w.Cells(a, "h").EntireRow.Copy dest.Cells(d, 1)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try If w.Cells(a, "h").value <> ""